# ActiveModel not found in rails Controller with namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

My routes are like

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :teams
end
```

I create a model in /app/models/TeamModel.rb like

```
class TeamModel
  include ActiveModel::Model
end
```

In my controller I try to use the TeamModel

```
class Admin::TeamsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @team = TeamModel.new
  end
end
```

The 500 error I get is

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Admin::TeamsController::TeamModel):
```

I get it that I hav etc include the model in controller but it is already in the models folder. Assuming, ActiveModel is part of rails and I do not have to include it as a gem

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create a file called `TeamModel.rb` file or `team_model.rb`?

Comment: as soon as I read this comment I realized my mistake. I did name it TeamModel and changing it fixed the issue. Thanks. Do you want to answer this instead of a comment so I can mark it complete?